# Light abrasion on the valve stems - is the outlook gloomy?

Tags: chevrolet, valve, rebuild, ls1

### Background

I'm rebuilding my LS1 Chevy. The cylinder heads came back from the machine shop fresh with a 5-angle valve job and mechanically-lapped valve faces and seats.

What concerns me is the presence of some light chatter marks on the valve stems. They're not so deep that I can feel them with my fingernail. I suspect this wear occurred as a consequence of the mechanical lapping since I didn't give the valves to the machine shop like  this.

### Pre-valve job

[image]

### Post-valve job pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Questions

- Should I be concerned about this level of wear on the stems?
- What would happen if I reused these valves with new valve guides?

Comment: Have you measured the stems for wear : ovality etc with a good micrometer? That should give you a good idea of whether you should use or replace them.

Comment: ya what Mike said, there will (should) be a service limits listed in the service manual. but if you don't have it (get it) you could measure a surface that doesn't contact the guide and get a good idea how much it's worn, if any. that's what I need to do working on lot of generic Chinese made engines with zero documentation.  that said using worn valves in New guides will just speed up the wear off both cuz of the extra play